# How can I fix Android studio emulator?

Tags: android

The gradle keeps failing.

Is there something I can do to the code to fix this?

```
2023-11-13 12:31:44,401 [1658408]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--continue, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyQuicksort\.gradle, -Pandroid.injected.enableStableIds=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.api=29, -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=x86, --stacktrace]
2023-11-13 12:31:44,406 [1658413]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.s.e.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --continue -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyQuicksort\.gradle -Pandroid.injected.enableStableIds=true -Pandroid.injected.build.api=29 -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=x86 --stacktrace
2023-11-13 12:31:44,462 [1658469]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - C:\Users\ellis\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-11-13 12:31:44,797 [1658804]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - unknown option: -qt-hide-window
2023-11-13 12:31:44,797 [1658804]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - please use -help for a list of valid options
2023-11-13 12:31:44,900 [1658907]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - Process finished with exit code 1
2023-11-13 12:31:48,507 [1662514]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Error retrieving list of excluded patterns: Error code 5: Access is denied.
2023-11-13 12:31:48,507 [1662514]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Windows Defender status: UNKNOWN_STATUS; projectDirExcluded? false
2023-11-13 12:31:48,520 [1662527]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/jbr
2023-11-13 12:31:48,525 [1662532]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models.
2023-11-13 12:31:48,525 [1662532]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, build result = com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.AssembleInvocationResult@3f610202
2023-11-13 12:31:48,530 [1662537]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 4 s 129 ms
2023-11-13 12:31:48,537 [1662544]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio2/jbr
2023-11-13 12:31:48,540 [1662547]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.ExecutionUtil - Error running 'app':<br>The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 has terminated.
java.lang.RuntimeException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Tried just running it but it keeps failing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To be able to help you, we need some more information about your problem. What is the exact gradle command that is causing the issue? Also, what have you already tried to fix the issue (e.g., have you already tried to run the app on a real phone or on another emulator)? **Note:** To include this information, click on "Edit" and edit your question rather than posting a comment. Cheers :)